# Batch file: parsing command line inputs

Tags: windows, batch-file, validation

I am working on a batch file to use as a wrapper for some data processing modules that are already written, with the goal of being able to run some in parallel and others serially as needed/processing power allows. The underlying modules require one input (a path contained in double quotes), and optionally another path contained in double quotes and/or a set of flags, and I am trying to figure out how to test these inputs. I currently have

```
:TEST_PARAMS
REM Make sure parameters are correct; if not, display a usage message
IF NOT "%1"=="" (SET SUBBASENAME=%1
) ELSE (
    GOTO :USAGE
)
IF NOT "%2"=="" (SET ATLASBASENAME=%2
) ELSE (
    SET ATLASBASENAME=%DEFAULTATLAS%
)
IF NOT "%3"=="" (SET FLAGS=%3
) ELSE (
    SET FLAGS=""
)
GOTO :START_SVREG
```

This seems to parse everything correctly if things are input in the correct order. However, I also wanted to check if the flags (which will be preceeded by '-') are popping up as the first or second inputs, and if they are, to display a usage message/set the variables correctly as needed. I figured the easiest way to do this would be to see if the first character of these strings is a '-', but I can't find any way to do this. I found a snippet of code that checks if a string contains a certain substring by replacing the substring with empty strings and then seeing if the resulting string is the same as the original, but this wouldn't work as people might legitimately have hyphens somewhere else in their path(s). Is there a way to check whether the first character of a string matches a given character in a batch file, or a better way of doing what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer the argument to an environment variable, and then use a SET substring operation to look at the first character. (Type `HELP SET` from the command line to get info about substring operations)

```
@echo off
set "var=%~1"
if defined var if "%var:~0,1%" equ "-" echo arg 1 is a flag
```

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need to check "-" in any batch file argument because as a batch file creator you will know what commands can be processed or not. Means if use "-b" then you know how to process it or if user passed "-t" you will know how to process. In your batch file you just need to process all the arguments, no matter in which order they are, and in your batch file you will have sections to process it. Here is an example Batch file which can process any number of arguments with "-" or "/" used with them:

```
@echo off

if [%1]==[] goto usage
:CHECKFORSWITCHES
@echo Execute the Command
IF '%1'=='/param1' GOTO PARAM1
IF '%1'=='-param2' GOTO PARAM2
IF '%1'=='/param3' GOTO PARAM3
IF '%1'=='-param4' GOTO PARAM4
IF '%1'=='/param5' GOTO PARAM5
goto :eof

:PARAM1
@echo This is Param1
set var=%1
set var2=%var:~0,1%
echo %var2%
SHIFT
goto :CHECKFORSWITCHES
:PARAM2
@echo This is Param2
SHIFT
goto :CHECKFORSWITCHES
:PARAM3
@echo This is Param3
SHIFT
goto :CHECKFORSWITCHES
:PARAM4
@echo This is Param4
set var=%1
set var2=%var:~0,1%
echo %var2%
SHIFT
goto :CHECKFORSWITCHES
:PARAM5
@echo This is Param5
SHIFT
goto :CHECKFORSWITCHES
:usage
@echo Usage: %0 ^<Write your command here^>
exit /B 1
```

Above script also checks for very first character of any parameter so if you need to use that code separately, you sure can use it however I don't think it is a good way to do it.

Above if you need to write some logic based in "-" or "/", just use IF %var2%=='/" GOTO XXX and you can do whatever you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using the batch file as a kind of interface to modules that were compiled with Matlab, so it doesn't actually do anything with the flags--it just passes them on if they're present. Each module does its own checking, but I was hoping to be able to check before calling them, so that the user isn't flooded with usage messages.